# Menu vertical fixo com css e bootstrap

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-3

gostaria de uma ajuda preciso fazer um menu vertical fixo porem ao lado deles existe uma linha com alguns círculos que vão me indicar em que sessão da página estou porem não faço ideia de como chegar nesse resultado gostaria só de algumas dicas e ou alguns exemplos ou documentação que possa estudar que me auxilie nesse menu lembrando que também estou usando bootstrap3. Segue a imagem do layout do menu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue os códigos:

O HTML:

```
  <div id="right-menu">
            <ul class="menu list-unstyled text-right">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Franquia</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

O CSS:

```
 #right-menu{
      position: fixed;
      right: 150px;
      top: 30%;

      .no-padding{
        padding: 0;
      }

          .menu{
            li{
              margin: 10px;
            }
            a{
              color: @white;
              font-size: 1.2em;
              font-weight: 400;
                &:hover{
                  text-decoration: @link-hover-decoration;
                  color: @navbar-default-link-hover-color;
                }
            }
          }
        }
```

OBS: estou ultilizando o Less e o menu que eu quero e parecido com o site do [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav) lateral e quando rola mostra em que parte está

Comment: Acredito que se pegar a div que contém todos esses elementos e der um position:fixed, resolve...Para obter mais ajuda de outros usuários é bom colocar o código....

Comment: @MagicHat nao amigo isso ai eu ja fix oque quero fazer e aquela barra lateral com os circulos entende

Comment: Mas é eu que tô dizendo, se colocar todos os elementos, incluindo as pelotas, tudo em uma div e posicionar com fixed... Mas pra orientar exatamente eu preciso ver o html e o css, capiche?

Comment: ata entendi kkkkkkk desculpa ai vou editar o post e colocar o código

Comment: @MagicHat pronto amigo está la o codigo

Comment: O que está acontecendo ? Num fica fixo ou o que?

Comment: e que é assim eu quero fazer aquele traço na vertical com as bolinhas dentro tipo tem o menu fixo a direita do lado dele tem uma barra na imagem da para ver isso e nesse barra tem circulos pequenos cada circulo indica uma section do site eu ano sei como fazer isso entende nao sei se existe uma maneira correta de se fazer

Comment: naos ei se fui bem claro mais e isso sabe por isso quero uma ajuda ou uma explicação de como faz ou ate memo links de exemplos me ajudariam

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41570/discussion-between-magichat-and-kirito).

Comment: ok amigo vou logar

Comment: @MagicHat amigo nao esta indo o chado so fica carregando posso te add no facebook

Comment: Vê se a resposta tá de acordo e fecha (se tiver correta) clicando do lado ali...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vê se ajuda.

Seguinte tá no css basicão aí se adapta. No seu caso acho que vai querer usar imagens ao invés dos tipos de lista padrão.

Daí é só substituir por `list-style-image: url('suaimagem.jpg');`

Então se precisa 2 imagens uma pra on outra pra of, e no caso eu coloquei evento :hover, aí se põe o que for necessário.

```css
ul.exemplo {list-style-type: circle;}

li:hover {list-style-type: disc;}

.vertical{
float:left;
position:absolute;
margin-left:26px;
height:90px;
border-left:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
 <div id="right-menu">
            <div class="vertical"></div>
            <ul class="exemplo">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Franquia</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Dá pra fazer de uma série de formas... Mas tá aí uma simplex...

[Aqui pode ajudar](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp)

Qualquer coisa vai comentando que agente acerta.

Comment: opa amigo daora mesmo so que tipo ta osso colocar do outro lado essa propiedade list-style so da para ser na esquerda nao consigp lococala na direita ?

Comment: Patrão dai se põe imagem ... e direciona....

Comment: vle amigo me ajudou muito malz ter demorado para marcar a resposta fiquei sem net

Comment: relax...bom que consegui..te a próxima...